# (Physics 2, Waves) Why does $\tan(\theta) = dy/dx$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, free-body-diagram, string, calculus

In the following example:

[image]

At the very last step, how does the author get that $\tan(\theta) = dy/dx$? To which $dy$ and $dx$ is this referring to? It can't be the same $dx$ that is labelled in the diagram, can it? Where do these $dy$ and $dx$ come from?

Comment: It is that dx. The dm is almost the hypothenuse, dy is then the vertical third leg of that triangle. tangent is a slope, by definition of tangent. Thus, there is an angle (very close to the vert opp angle of $\theta_1$) where it is the tangent of

Comment: How is this homework? It's question about a derivation for equation of motion of a string. The close voters (and you know who you are) need to examine their views about helping other people understand physics as well as they do.

Comment: In my experience the slope $dy/dx$ is usually denoted $\tan\psi$ to avoid conflation of $\psi$ with the polar angle $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) $\tan \theta = \frac yx $,

[image]

And if you look closely in given page it says :

> On our diagram, however, the deformation has been exaggerated for clarity.

So what author has in mind is that deformation is *infinitesimally* small, so deformed arc is almost same by length as right triangle hypotenuse.

Answer (score 0):

tan theta =y/x

for a very small length tan theta =dy/dx